# Как реализовать передачу в контроллер атрибутов элемента, созданного динамически с помощью Snap.SVG

Tags: angularjs, svg, snapsvg

Вопрос в следующем: есть у меня поле размером 39х32 созданное с помощью `Snap.SVG`. В нем находится 1248 элементов. Каждый со своим номером, атрибутами `col` и `row`.

Задача стоит следующая: при нажатии на элемент в контроллер должны прийти его координаты (col, row) и id.

Пробовал совершить такое дело несколькими способами. Первый способ (ожидаемо) просто не дал никакого результата:

```
var dist = 24;
var tr = {fill:'transparent', stroke:'#000', strokeWidth:1};
var id = 1;

field = Snap('#svgField');

for(var i=1; i<=39; i++){
    for(var j=1; j<=32; j++){
        var circle = field.circle(dist*i, dist*j, dits/3).attr(tr);
        circle.attr({id: id, col: i, row: j, 'ng-click':"someFunc()"});
    }
}
```

Появлялось поле, все хорошо, кроме того, что `ng-click` вообще не реагировал. Да. `Angular` я только начал изучать.
 Контроллер не ловит - значит что-то не так. Начал гуглить. Оказалось, что есть некий сервис у ангуляра `$compile`, который перекомпилирует (я же правильно понял?) элемент DOM и создает тот самый `Two Way Data-Binding`.

Вот один из примеров, на которые я наткнулся при поиске ответов на свой вопрос:
http://jsfiddle.net/aZB5F/4/

Но это все вроде бы как ничего смотрится, когда элементов не много. Это во-первых, а во-вторых метод, который распознает (в данном примере нажатие правой клавиши мыши) лежит внутри директивы, и я не вижу способа передачи данных в контроллер. Плюс ко всему у `Snap.SVG` для элементов есть свой метод `.click()`, в который как раз можно прописать действие клика по элементу.

А усложняется все еще и тем, что мне нужно получить примерное такой результат: нажимаем на 1 элемент - и все элементы вокруг него становятся другого цвета, а данные о нажатом элементе отправляются на сервер (node.js) через socket.

Подобный вопрос я задал на тостере, но там получил довольно скудный ответ без объяснений:

> если это все не привязано к данным а просто UI - то просто по старинке делаем все в директиве в link.
>   Если зависим от данных - то тогда надо дата биндинг подключать и все
>   такое.

Но вот как можно было бы это сделать к огромному количеству элементов я так и не нашел :(

Уже было перепробовано множество разных вариантов. И создавал поле в контроллере, как в примере выше и пытался $compile данное поле, и пытался применить $compile к только что созданному объекту snap.svg, и даже вытаскивал из этого объекта его outerHTML, и к нему пытался применить $compile. Все без результатов. Я явно делаю что-то не так.

Вот мои последние попытки. Поле отрисовывается и все хорошо, но клик обрабатывается для каждого элемента по отдельности. И попытки вытащить соседний элемент приводили к ошибкам:

```
svgField.$inject = ['$compile'];
function svgField($compile) {
var directive = {
    template: '<svg version="1.1" id="svgField" class="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="960px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 960 792" ng-init="Ctrl.fieldDraw"></svg>',
    restrict: 'E'
};
return directive;
function link(scope, element, attrs){

    console.log('in field directive');

    var dist = 24;
    var id = 1;

    var field = Snap("#svgField");

    var tr = {
        fill:'transparent',
        stroke: '#000',
        strokeWidth: 1
    };

    for(var i=1; i<=39; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= 32; j++) {

            var cir = field.circle(dist*i, dist*j, dist/3).attr(tr);
            cir.attr({id: id, row: i, col: j});
            cir.click(function(){console.log(this)});

            console.log(cir.node.outerHTML);

            cir = $compile(cir.node.outerHTML)(scope);
            id++;
        }
    }
}
```

Я не прошу за меня писать код. Прошу лишь помочь хотя бы каким-то понятным примером использования $compile в таком случае. Потому, что snap.svg создает объект, а вот как к этому объекту применить $compile я что-то не пойму.

Добавлено поле в Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/wt5fP2hUZkNr4IvY2C03?p=preview

Comment: можете рабочий пример привести на [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) или[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? пример того что уже есть

Comment: я с Plunker и jsFiddle знаком поверхностно. В jsFiddle пример вообще не захотел работать, а в Plunker ругается на Snap. В консоли увидите. В общем-то это рабочий код. У меня появляются все круги и в консоли при нажатии на каждый вылазит его номер col и row, а так же id. А вот как передать из в контроллер, и тем более из контроллера вызвать изменения в 9 окружающих кругах.

http://plnkr.co/edit/wt5fP2hUZkNr4IvY2C03?p=preview

Comment: так у где ссылка-то? :-) ага увидел :-) первая ошибка была в опечатке: `sctipt`

Comment: похоже была какая-то проблема с загрузкой снапа, поправил планкр: http://plnkr.co/edit/MIqLNcfy4Tmgf2SVOC7a?p=preview

Comment: Ну plunker это не главное :) Но и за это спасибо. Сейчас у себя изменю еще.

Comment: ну это было важно чтобы можно было воспроизводить ошибку :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подход такой: не вызывать $compile на каждый круг, а сначала собрать все вместе и уже вызвать для всего сразу.

Кроме того в примере ниже видно, что клик можно отлавливать и стандартным навешиванием click обработчика, и добавлением `ng-click` директивы.

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('AppController', ['$scope',
  function AppCtrl($scope) {
    console.log('in App Ctrl');
    $scope.clickedCircle = function(i, j) {
      console.log('in App Ctrl', 'row:', i, 'col:', j);
    }
  }
]);
app.directive('svgField', ['$compile',
  function svgField($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: true,
      template: '<svg version="1.1" id="svgField" class="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="960px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 960 792" ng-init="Ctrl.fieldDraw"></svg>',
      link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('in field directive');
        var dist = 24;

        var id = 1;

        var field = Snap("#svgField");

        var tr = {
          fill: 'transparent',
          stroke: '#000',
          strokeWidth: 1
        };

        for (var i = 1; i <= 39; i++) {
          for (var j = 1; j <= 32; j++) {

            var circle = field.circle(dist * j, dist * i, dist / 3).attr(tr);
            circle.attr({
              id: id,
              row: i + 1,
              col: j + 1,
              'ng-click': 'clickedCircle(' + i + ',' + j + ')',
            }).click(function() {
              console.log('snap click', this);
              console.log(scope.clickedCircle);
            });
            id++;
          }
        }
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script data-require="snap.svg@*" data-semver="0.3.0" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <svg-field></svg-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Это вроде как то, что мне нужно. Спасибо большое. Пошел разбираться.

Comment: @JackDrakkar, пожалуйста :-)